# High bed, long brace removal

Tags: bedroom

We have high sleeper bed that will fit sideways across our narrow bedroom(194 cm). We are adapting it to fit snugly against the walls.

There is a window with a radiator underneath that will be partly covered by the bed. The middle support beam that holds the legs in place will be in the way.

If we attach the legs to the walls , will we be able to make do without this beam?[image]

Comment: if you can otherwise restrict lateral movement/forces it should be ok without it, they are typically to prevent reaching a tipping point where the primary supports topple.

Comment: The support brace goes across the room where the radiator is, so we could put it above the radiator but would prefer to do without it if we can